# How to add shadow on constraint layout items?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile

I want to add a shadow to a note in a constraint layout. I have tried using elevation but that does not seem to work. Also if I try to use a separate file for styling the background, if I apply it the backgroud colour of the note also changes. This app allows to specify the color of the note when it is created and I would like to keept it that way. But as I mentioned, if I specify background from my drawables the background collour of the note also changes. I have tried using card views as well but it just covers the item and nothing appears. This what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/row_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notes_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:maxLength="350"
            android:maxLines="12"
            android:text="Example text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title_text"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_text"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYwuX.png)

I would like the notes to have a shadow like so:
[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in3Uw.png)

Howw can I achieve this?

Comment: add a background to the item you want and set its elevation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet this is what you were searching for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notes_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Example Text"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title_text"/>
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is also important to use a `RelativeLayout` in the `CardView`, here between `CardView` and `TextView` (as I did).
Happy coding buddy! :)

[image: The result]

Comment: Where have you seen RelativeLayout recommended over ConstraintLayout? The official documentation for RelativeLayout says right at the top that you should use ConstraintLayout instead: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative I think RelativeLayout is likely to be deprecated soon.

Comment: `Note that the documentation recommend to work with RelativeLayout instead of ConstraintLayout for such kind of operations.` unless you have actual source for this, it's just nonsense.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I got that wrong. Was a long day yesterday. It was the other way around. Thank you for the advise. I made an edit in my post. Cheers!

Comment: still, no point in rewriting what OP already had (with constraint layout) to use a relative layout for no reason

Answer (score 1):

**Here a example to use shadow in your layout with cardView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Card Example"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/LightBlack"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/locationSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Check the image It's look like**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to get shadows In your layout, you must use he CardView layout, above your constraint layout or below it depending on how you configure your XML layout. You can use it from the androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0 dependency. It has the elevation attribute which generates shadows.

Comment: Could you explain more how could I achieve this. I am a complete beginner and was following a tutorial but also wanted to include the shadows which are not part of it.

Comment: Sure. First you need to add the CardView dependency to your project. You can do that by adding this line, implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0' to the build.gradle module:app file. One you've done this. You can open the XML layout and add the card view layout. In your layout you can simply change the second constraintLayout to CardView as you don't really need the second constraintLayout and replacing it with a cardview will serve the same purpose. After you do this, set cardElevation to your desired value, eg 10dp to get shadows in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial at [GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cardview-in-android-with-example/) and also [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-cardview).
You can also read official docs at  [CardView Based layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview)  and [cardview widget](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView)